# How to go about proving theorems about category theory?

Tags: proof-writing, category-theory, natural-transformations, yoneda-lemma

1. Prove that the functor $V : Cat → Set$ that sends a category $\mathcal{C}$ to its set of arrows, is represented by the category ${0 \rightarrow 1}$ with two objects and a single non identity morphism between them; do not forget to prove that the bijection $V(\mathcal{C}) \cong Hom_{Cat}({0 \rightarrow 1}, \mathcal{C})$ you found is natural!"
2. Prove that there exists a category of relations, where the objects are all sets, and given sets $A, B$, the set of morphisms $A \rightarrow B$ is the powerset of $A \times B$.
   Given a relation $R \in \mathcal{P}(A \times B)$ and a relation $S \in \mathcal{P}(B \times C)$, define the composition $S \circ R \in \mathcal{P}(A \times C)$ as the subset $\{(a,c)\in A \times C \ | \ \exists \ b \in B$ such that $(a,b)\in R, (b,c)\in S \}$.
   Check that this defines an associative composition operation, i.e. $(S \circ R) \circ T = S \circ (R \circ T)$ whenever it makes sense. Given this composition law, there is only one possible choice for what is the identity relation $I \subseteq A \times A$: which one?

These are the types of questions I am tying to solve. I start by listing all the facts I know, the lemmas I can use, the properties of natural transformations, functors etc.

So for the 1st question, $V$ sends a category to its set of morphisms , and we want to prove that $V(\mathcal{C}) \cong Hom_{Cat}(0 \rightarrow 1, \mathcal{C} )$, the $Hom$-functor that maps $\mathcal{C}$ to the set of morphisms between $0 \rightarrow 1$ and $\mathcal{C}$.
In $0 \rightarrow 1$, we have only two morphisms, identity.
I know that we need to prove the square from $V(\mathcal{C})$ to $Hom(0 \rightarrow 1,\mathcal{C})$, to $V(\mathcal{D})$ to $Hom(0 \rightarrow 1,\mathcal{D})$ commutes, that the natural transformation is an isomorphism(has a well defined inverse)

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V(\mathcal{C}) @>a^{\mathcal{C}} >> Hom(0 \rightarrow 1, \mathcal{C})\\
@V {V(F)} VV @VV {Hom(0 \rightarrow 1,F)} V \\
V(\mathcal{D}) @>a^{\mathcal{D}} >> Hom(0 \rightarrow 1, \mathcal{D})\\
\end{CD}
$$

And after that, I am totally lost.

I will gladly accept any general tips on approaching these types of questions as well as more specific tips, especially for the 2nd question

Comment: Hi: please try to focus your question. I realize you want to ask for "general advice" but this does not work well in our Q+A system. It would be great to focus on each question in separate posts, and I'm sure those offering solutions would be glad to elaborate on their thought process, so you might also glean your general advice from that.

Comment: Please also see the [mathjax tutorials](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help formatting questions. In this case, a rather talented editor has pulled off the formatting for you

Comment: The titular question: for the more elementary things like exercises, the bulk of the solution almost always rests in correctly understanding and unwinding the definitions, and then just following what they say like a computer program: there is only one possible thing you can try, and trying it will bring success. This is paraphrased from the preface of Leinster’s “Basic Category Theory” and I found it to be really excellent advice

Comment: Thanks, will do better the next time!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have some misunderstandigs about the definitions. So maybe it will help you when I describe the components of the natural transformation explicitly, you can then try to check that it is indeed natural.

I will denote the category $a \to b$ with two objects and one non-identity arrow by $\mathbf 2$. The category has exactly two objects $a$ and $b$, two identity arrows $id_a$ and $id_b$ and a single non-identity arrow $a\to b$, I give it the name $f$. The composition operations in $\mathbf 2$ are forced, for example $f\circ id_a$ must be $f$ because $\mathbf 2$ is a category. You sometimes write $\{0,1\}$ or even $(0,1)$ for that category, which looks a bit weird to me.

What data does a functor $F:\mathbf 2\to \mathcal C$ contain? The functor $F$ must send the arrow $f$ to some arrow $F(f)$ in $\mathcal C$. The action on the remaining objects and arrows is forced. We must have that $F(a)$ and $F(b)$ must be the domain and codomain of $F(f)$ and that $F(id_a)$ and $F(id_b)$ are the identities of domain and codomain. Let me write $\mathcal C_1$ for the set of arrows in $\mathcal C$, i.e. $\mathcal C_1 = V(\mathcal C)$ in your notation. We see that there is a bijection  $$\mathcal C_1 = Cat(\mathbf 2,\mathcal C)$$
Given an arrow $g:x\to y$ in $\mathcal C$, we can define a functor $F:\mathbf 2\to \mathcal C$ by setting $F(a) = x, F(b)=y,F(f) = g$, $F(id_a) =id_x$ and $F(id_b) = id_y$. Conversely, given a functor $F:\mathbf 2\to \mathcal C$ we get an arrow by evaluating $F$ at $f$. The arrow is $F(f) : F(a) \to F(b)$. You can check that the two functions are inverse to each other. I have described the component of the natural isomorphism at $\mathcal C$ for you, your job is now to check that it is natural. This means that given a functor $G:\mathcal C \to \mathcal D$, you have to check that the corresponding square of functions commutes. Remember that $Cat(\mathbf 2,G)$ acts by post-composition on functors. I hope this is enough to get you started. If not, write me a comment! :)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the detailed response! I have a few questions. So the key to solving this question comes from realizing there's one determining part of *F*, the one that maps *a -> b*, and the rest is mostly arbitrary(?) So when trying to solve other questions, I should be looking for such key parts and trying to define the rest according to those (?). Also, the "bijection" part still doesn't make intuitive sense to me. Like I get it on paper, but the fact that the set of all morphisms in an arbitrary category is isomorphic to such a tiny set fees weird lol, not that it matters.

Comment: Or am I supposed to focus on the fact that since we have 2 objects in the first category, we can just map those to any two objects in $\pmb C$ that have a morphism in between. So if we were looking at a hom-Functor from a single object category to an arbitrary category, that would be isomorphic to the set of objects in a category(?)

Comment: @noCrayCray The category $\mathbb 2$ may be tiny, but the set of functors $\mathbb 2\to \mathcal C$ is not. This is not unusual. E.g. the one point set $\mathbf 1$ may be tiny, but the set of functions $Set(\mathbf 1,A)$ is not necessarily. You should focus on the fact that a functor $F:\mathbf 2 \to \mathcal C$ is exactly determined by $F(f)$. The rest of the functor is not arbitrary, it is forced!